# Quick question: Curvature form of a connection on the trivial bundle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, curvature

Let $L=\mathbb{R}^2\times U(1)$ be the trivial $U(1)$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define a connection $\nabla=d+A$ where $A=fdx+gdy$ is an $\mathbb{R}$ valued $1$-form on $L$. That is, $\nabla$ gives a distribution $\mathcal{H}$ on $L$ - the horizontal distribution.

The distribution $\mathcal{H}$ is obtained as the graph of $-A$ as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. A horizontal lift $\tilde{X}$ of a vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $\tilde{X}=(X,-A(X))$.

Let $\alpha$ be the projection onto the vertical direction on $L$ i.e. $\ker(\alpha)=\mathcal{H}$, and define the curvature $2$-form $\Omega_{\nabla}$ of the connection $\nabla$ by

$$\Omega_{\nabla}(X,Y)=\alpha([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}])$$

> The following is expected to be true
>   $$\Omega_{\nabla}=-dA?$$

Here is my confusion:

Let $z$ be the local vertical coordinate, $X=\partial_x$ and $Y=\partial_y$. Then $\tilde{X}=-f\partial_z+\partial_x$ and $\tilde{Y}=-g\partial_z+\partial_y$. And
$$-dA(X,Y)=-X(A(Y)+Y(A(X))+A([X,Y])=-\partial_xg+\partial_yf$$
while
$$[\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]=(f(\partial_zg)-g(\partial_zf)-\partial_xg+\partial_yf)\partial_z$$
therefore
$$\Omega_{\nabla}(X,Y)=\alpha([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}])=f(\partial_zg)-g(\partial_zf)-\partial_xg+\partial_yf.$$
Where is the mistake?

Comment: This appears to be a pure math question.

Comment: I don't have time to go through this right now, so I dunno if this causes any problems or not, but $A$ should be imaginary valued. The Lie algebra of $\mathrm{U}(1)$ is $i\mathbb{R}$, the reason why the vector potential is real in QED is because you take $A=iq\mathcal{A}$, where $A$ is the connection and $\mathcal{A}$ is the vector potential.

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/36782/

Answer (score 0):

$f$ and $g$ are defined on the base space to begin with. You would need to extend to functions on the total space in order to define taking $\partial_z$.